# SOQL Statement Help

Tags: soql, community

How do I a condition to the my statement below to exclude product `Name` not containing "RENEWAL".  The field is `Name` on `OpportunityLineItem`.

```
SELECT Name, StageName, Amount, CloseDate
FROM Opportunity
WHERE AccountId = '0017000000MgHZv'
AND Amount > 0
ORDER BY AMOUNT DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you would exclude opportunities that don't include products with renewal:

```
SELECT Name, StageName, Amount, CloseDate
FROM Opportunity
WHERE AccountId = '0017000000MgHZv'
AND Amount > 0
AND id in 
(select opportunityid from opportunitylineitem Where name Like 'RENEWAL%')
ORDER BY AMOUNT DESC
```

If you only need to grab line items where that condition is true, then:

```
SELECT Opportunity.Name, Opportunity.StageName, Opportunity.Amount, Opportunity.CloseDate
FROM OpportunityLIneItem
WHERE Opportunity.AccountId = '0017000000MgHZv'
AND Opportunity.Amount > 0
AND name Like 'RENEWAL%'
ORDER BY Opportunity.AMOUNT DESC
```

If you can give a little more detail on what you're trying to accomplish with the query, I can try to give you some additional guidance.

Comment: He's trying to look at a child object. You should probably also use a leading wildcard.

Comment: Missed that on the first edit